# Sort digits by their first occurrence in pi

Tags: code-golf, number, sorting, pi

Given a non-negative number `n`, sort the digits of `n` by their first occurrence in [pi](http://www.piday.org/million/).

Input can be taken via function cli argument, or STDIN and as a string, char[] or integer. You may output via return value, exit status or STDOUT.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67223/31516)

Comment: Can we take input and output as strings, or as arrays of digits?

Comment: @ETHproductions Clarified.

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be an integer?

Comment: It is guaranteed to be an integer or a string representation of that integer

Comment: Will the input ever contain leading zeroes?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No.

Comment: A few test cases would be nice.

Comment: Now that 12 answers are already present, all of which performing the same thing, if you are still unclear what is being asked, then it is not the problem of the question.

Comment: You don't really need to specify those i/o methods (the i/o formats are fine though), as they are the PPCG defaults.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
ox+.n0
```

[Try it here.](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=ox%2B.n0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%221023456789%22%0A%22123456789%22%0A%223218204911386623457%22%0A%220%22%0A%221%22)

*-1 thanks to [Leaky Nun](/u/48934): The input will provide the `0` if it's ever needed.*
*Trivial -1 thanks to [Jakube](/u/29577): Backtick not needed (ah, how did I miss that, HOW?!?).*

Comment: Woohoo, this even beats 05AB1E! Edit: it doesn't beat 05AB1E, and I don't wanna steal :(

Comment: I found it. You don't need the `0` at the end. If the input has a `0`, the `0` would be provided by the input; if the input does not have a `0`, it won't matter.

Comment: @LeakyNun and you can even save the backtick: `ox+.n0`

Comment: OK, disregard the first comment, thanks to LeakyNun and Jakube, I again beat 05AB1E, I hope for good this time.

Comment: That's a beautiful amount of implicit input.

Comment: @isaacg One third of the program `ox+.n0NNQ` can be implicit input, so it's cut away.

Answer (score 21):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan.

```python
lambda s:sorted(s,key="145926870".find)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59mm5OYm5SSqFBsVZxfVJKaolGsk51aaatkaGJqaWRmYW6gpJeWmZei@b@gKDOvRENJSS8rPzNPI01DydDI2MTUzNzC0gDBUtLU1PwPAA)

Comment: You can drop the `3`, since find will return `-1` when an item is not found.

Answer (score 17):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Leaky Nun* noting that filtering out duplicates is unnecessary.
Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Adnan*.

```
žqRvy†J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390X2FQWeWjhgVe//9bmlsYGhmbmJoZAAA)

**Explanation**

```
žq       # push pi to 15 decimals (contains all digits but 0)
  R      # reverse
   vy    # for each char in pi
     †J  # move it's occurrences in the input to the front
```

Comment: `13žsRvy†J` for 9 bytes

Comment: @LeakyNun: Oh yeah, duplicates doesn't matter. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you use `žq` instead of `13žs`?

Comment: @Adnan It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer [It works for me](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390X2FQWeWjhgVe//9bmlsYGhmbmJoZAAA)

Comment: @LeakyNun Whoops, I don't know what I typed then.

Comment: @Adnan: Yes of course. I didn't realize there was another pi constant :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

8 bytes of code, +1 for the `-P` flag.

```
¬ñ!bMP+U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@39ozeGNikm@Adqh//8rGRoZm5iamVtYGigp6AYAAA) Takes input as a string.

#### Explanation

```
¬ñ!bMP+'0  // Implicit input

¬          // Split the input into chars.
 ñ         // Sort each char in the resulting list by
  !b       //   its index in
    MP+U   //     Math.PI + the input.
-P         // Join the result back into a single string.
           // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
“ṀSṪw’ṾiµÞ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASYA2f//4oCc4bmAU@G5qnfigJnhub5pwrXDnv///yIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIg)

Takes input as a string of digits.

*-3 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

**Explanation**

```
“ṀSṪw’ṾiµÞ
        µ  - Separate chain into function “ṀSṪw’Ṿi and sort atom Þ.
         Þ - Sort the input by
       i   - Each digit's index in: 
“ṀSṪw’     - the literal 3145926870 ...
      Ṿ    - transformed into the list 3,1,4,5,9,2,6,8,7,0
```

Comment: I think `3145926870` can be represented as a 4-digit base-250 string (meaning it takes up 6 bytes instead of 10), but I'm not sure how to compress it as such.

Comment: Does Jelly not have a builtin for pi?

Comment: @mathjunkie but Jelly is not very efficient on string manipulation

Comment: @mathjunkie Yes, but the manipulations to the list take too many bytes

Comment: [`“ṀSṪw’`](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYc7DnQ3BD3euKn/UMPP/fwA) will give you `3145926870`.

Comment: If you take input and output as strings, can you get rid of the `D`/`Ḍ` in the main link?

Comment: @ETHproductions The `D` converts it to a list of numbers, not a string

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AScA2P//4oCc4bmAU@G5qnfigJnhub5pCsOHw57///8iMTIzNDU2Nzg5MCI "Jelly – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @ETHproductions hey, that was nice.

Comment: which allows you to do `“ṀSṪw’ṾiµÞ` for 10 bytes

Comment: @mathjunkie The pi builtin does not go far enough to include a zero, which is needed in Jelly since it's 1-indexed.

Answer (score 7):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>15</s> <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
r{P`#c}$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19UHZCgnFyr8v@/oYGRsYmpmbmFJQA)

*-3: Use a string based on the `P` pi variable instead of a literal.*
*-2: Decided I don't need to uniquify at all, since finding an index takes the first occurrence anyways.*
*-2: Thanks to [jimmy23013](/u/25180) for an interesting approach using x mod 65536.*

Explanation:

```
r{P`#c}$ e# Takes an input token
r        e# Take the integer as a string
 {P`#c}  e# Sorting key:
  P      e#  Push P (defaults to 3.141592653589793)
   `     e#  Convert to string representation
    #    e#  Find char's index in the string we made
         e#  A '.' will never be found in an integer, but it doesn't matter, since the shifting preserves ideal sorting.
         e#  A '0' will be indexed as -1.
     c   e#  Convert index to char
         e#  This first calculates index % 65536, and then converts to char. We need this because otherwise 0 would be indexed as -1, i.e. smallest index.
         e#  We don't need to convert back to integer, since we can use lexicographical sorting.
       $ e# Sort with key
```

Comment: Yay, beats MATL :)

Comment: https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19UHZCgnFyr8v@/oYGRsYmpmbmFJQA

Comment: @jimmy23013 Wow that's clever. It's almost like there's a builtin for int(x)%65536, and `ci` would even convert back to integer.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte thanks to Dennis (use any existing `0` in the input, clever.)

```
ØP;ṾiµÞ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394RoD1w537Mg9tPTzv////SoZGxiamZuYWlgZKAA)**

#### How?

```
ØP;ṾiµÞ - Main link: string s (char list)
     µÞ - sort the characters, c, of s by:
    i   -   first index of c in:
ØP      -     pi yield: 3.141592653589793
  ;     -     concatenate with left: [3.141592653589793, c]
   Ṿ    -     un-evaluate: "3.141592653589793,c" (a char list with the digit character c)
                                if any c is 0 ^ it will then be to the right of all others
```

Comment: ...and there I was searching for squares - `3820009` (sqrt of `14592468760081`) is still `3` digits in base `250`.

Comment: The `Ṿ` in your explanation is misplaced.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer - thanks, adjusted.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), 54 bytes

```js
f=
s=>[...s].sort((a,b)=>k[a]-k[b],k=`9150236874`).join``
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Uses strings for I/O.

Answer (score 6):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>85</s> 73 bytes

```c
*z=L"9150236874"-48;s(*a,*b){return z[*a]-z[*b];}f(*t,n){qsort(t,n,4,s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvfCoMgHEbve4ofwkBFoT9WRvQGvUHrwqIicG5LR1D06nPu5uPjcM7IR63M4j09mhZVSR6nWSFLgbiQtcVUMTqQc5vcZzNwdFT1POzQ19eMqWOGnG/73BwOlwlmSX35h1oNJtEZAazGget6aKBFSZqJvChlFVeyLHKRpUmM6iDNIYZ9tHoy2BHyR68tlDNGN23vBjFwgV7@O85aLdbz/Qc)

Comment: @ceilingcat, wow, it took my small mind forever to figure out what you did there!!

Comment: [69](https://tio.run/##JcpLCoMwFADAvacIgUIihvr/ELxBbxCyCKGxBn0t@ooL9epNC13PWGEnA0MIXjoWYwJ8d8@F@R7iLJVeCMlR@QtoQdOmrfOuKrOCKn8FfRyvN9qHWdh/cHmG2YzAeLRHhIyABJUmPbnRLC/Kqm7aLqXyR45hQja7TndgyLmMzvCxbjLDGsT2BQ), different IO

Comment: @l4m2 Nice!! I'll update my answer; when I get back to my laptop. [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcndCoIwGADQe59iDIpNHDn/ZfgGvYHsYowmjvUV@YUX6qu3gs7tscIGA1OMXjmWYgZ8c48X8wOkMldeCMVx9CfQguZt1xR9XcmSjv4Cet@fb1zY@f9cHfFuZmA82RJCZkCCoyYDuVJZlFXdSCnbrs@p@q1jmJHVLuEGDDlXyRE/1gUzLVGsXw)

Comment: @l4m2 [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcndCoMgGADQe59ChIG2ZNl/SG@wN5AuQmYk7ttY3@iievW5zu2x0oYRphi9djzBFMTmXh/ue0hUpr2UWqDxFxgky5q2zruqVAUz/gbDvr@/uHC8ni30EZ/jDFyQjVA6A1I0A@3pnam8KKtaKdW0Xcb0uY5jSle7hAdwFEKTI/6sC@O0RLn@AQ)

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 71 Bytes

The [regex solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118100/sort-digits-by-their-first-occurrence-in-pi/118149#118149) is shorter

```php
for(;~$c=_3145926870[$i++];)echo str_repeat($c,substr_count($argn,$c));
```

or

```
for(;~$c=_3145926870[$i++];)echo str_pad("",substr_count($argn,$c),$c);
```

[Online Versions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/728aba9d6915f74931bd96ea75f033286bb7187c)

### PHP, 78 Bytes

```php
for(;~$c=$argn[$i++];)$j[strpos("3145926870",$c)].=$c;ksort($j);echo join($j);
```

### PHP, 112 Bytes

```php
$a=str_split($argn);usort($a,function($x,$y){return strpos($d="3145926870",$x)<=>strpos($d,$y);});echo join($a);
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85430db5d9fd31f443de242338c6cfba544313fd)

Comment: I've added a [69 byte solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118421/29637). Maybe we can get it down to 66 byte together ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 50 bytes

```
n=gets;"3145926870".each_char{|c|$><<c*n.count(c)}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 78 bytes

```c
f(char*s){for(char*d="3145926870",*p;*d;d++)for(p=s;*p;)*p++-*d||putchar(*d);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#JYtNDoMgGAXXcoqGFR@0ifxDiIcxJaQuaonYlXp2KnY3mTevJvJ8jQstsKXP8uc4YMmV9sI42@M7zYHGEBmDVuShhNMAzYw9aNz3/F3bi9AI4ajTvN7e4zQTQBvqEsE9F1JpY53HEFB31oXgC9vYcy6ElEppbYy1zvkrO@oP)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
YP99Y$uj!y=sY"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x8ZYGkZqVKapVhpWxyp9P@/oZGxiamZuYWlAQA)

#### Explanation with an example

The symbol `;` is used as row separator in matrices. So `[1 2 3]` is a row vector, `[1; 2; 3]` is a column vector, and `[1 2; 3 4]` is a square matrix. The latter can also be represented, for clarity, as

```
[1 2;
 3 4]
```

Consider input `2325` as an example.

```
YP     % Push approximation of pi as a double (predefined literal)
       % 3.14159265358979
99Y$   % Variable-precision arithmetic with 99 digits. Gives a string.
       % The input 3.14159265358979 is recognized as representing pi
       % STACK: '3.141592653589793238462 ··· 707'
u      % Unique entries, keeping order of their first appearance
       % STACK: '3.145926870'
j      % Input line as a string
       % STACK: '3.145926870', '2352'
!      % Transpose
       % STACK: '3.145926870', ['2'; '3';'5'; '2']
y      % Duplicate the second-top element in the stack
       % STACK: '3.145926870', ['2'; '3';'5'; '2'], '3.145926870'
=      % Test for equality, with broadcast. This gives a matrix with
       % all pairwise comparisons)
       % STACK: '3.145926870', [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0;
       %                        1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
       %                        0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
       %                        0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
s      % Sum of each column
       % STACK: '3.145926870', [1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 0]
Y"     % Run-length decoding. Implicitly display
       % STACK: '3522'
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <strike>66</strike> 65 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to Titus.

```
while(~$d=_3145926870[++$i])echo preg_filter("/[^$d]/",'',$argn);
```

Answer (score 2):

## C# Interactive, <strike>37</strike> 36 Bytes

```cs
i.OrderBy(c=>"145926870".IndexOf(c))
```

Actually you have to execute this in the C# interactive for proper results, but I guess this is what you meant with *exit status*. The variable *i* actually is the input variable (it can be for example a string), so it's basically the method parameter.

I think the code itself is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Where's the `3`?

Comment: @Paul it's not neccessary, as it returns -1 if the element isn't found.

Comment: This is just a snippet of code though, I'm pretty sure even in interactive you have to specify why `i` is somewhere so it can be taken as input. Also if you're saying C# you have to include `using System.Linq;` into the byte count. However, if this is Interactive you should specify the language as C# Interactive not solely C#.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I updated it to C# Interactive. The using isn't neccesaary in the interactive, as it's included automatically.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 6 bytes

Had to realise that `0` is not present in the standard length pi constant.

```
Σтžsyk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@39u8cWmo/uKK7P//7e0MDczNTE2MjQAAA)

```
Σтžsyk
Σ      Sort by the result of code
 тžs   Push 100 digits of pi
   yk  Index of digit in pi
```

Comment: Too bad you needed that zero for this method. It should be optimal for this language at least. Can't ask for more than that :)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
{⍵[⍵⍋⍨14⍕○1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR79ZoIH7U2/2od4WhyaPeqY@mdxvG1v5Pe9Q24VFv36O@qZ7@j7qaD603ftQ2EcgLDnIGkiEensH/0xTUDQ2MjE1MzcwtLNW5QFxjU3MIy8DIxMxCHQA)

`○1` Pi times 1.

`14⍕` convert to a string with 14 decimal digits. This includes all unique digits except 0.

`⍵⍋⍨` the indices that would sort the input string `⍵` according to order given by the previous string.

`⍵[...]` index with those indices into the input to sort it.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 110 bytes

```
String c(String s){String r="";for(char i:"3145926870".toCharArray())r+=s.replaceAll("[^"+i+"]","");return r;}
```

**Explanation:**

```
String c(String s){                       // Method with String parameter and String return-type
  String r="";                            //  Result String
  for(char i:"3145926870".toCharArray())  //  Loop over the characters of "3145926870"
    r+=s.replaceAll("[^"+i+"]","");       //   Append the result-String with all the occurrences of the current character
                                          //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;                               //  Return the result-String
}                                         // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#LY5NC4JAFEX3/YrHW81giB@ZY9JCWrdqKQbTZDUwqbwZAwl/u03g7nDvhXOVkdbC@bsBsE46rWC5ONLdExRbwfLvSnRELB89MfWSBPqAabzLimQv8ghD1598WhHJiXFOwdGG1A5GqrYyhmF9xUAH2OAWkZfUupE6oHJeAIbxZrx49X96fYe31N3qrxuQ/P8P4DJZ177DfnTh4CtnOqaYrKOG89IP5s28LHGS7rJ9LopIpEUm4jwRHuIf)

```
class M{
  static String c(String s){String r="";for(char i:"3145926870".toCharArray())r+=s.replaceAll("[^"+i+"]","");return r;}
  
  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("12345678908395817288391"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
33311145599922688888770
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 38 bytes

```
#(sort-by(zipmap"3145926870"(range))%)
```

Input in string, returns a sequence of characters. `zipmap` creates a "dictionary" object, which can be used in a function context as well.

```
(f "1234")
(\3 \1 \4 \2)
```

If input digits were guaranteed to be unique then you could simply do `#(filter(set %)"3145926870")`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>69</strike> 68

```
for(;(~$d=$argn[$j++])||~$c=_3145926870[$i+++$j=0];)$c==$d&&print$d;
```

Still beaten by [preg_filter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118149/29637) but I thought it was quite nice itself. Maybe someone can golf off some bytes.

Comment: `$c!=$d?:print$d` as alternative for `$c==$d&&print$d` I only see in the moment

Comment: `_3145926870` instead of `"3145926870" save 1 Byte

Comment: `for(;(~$d=$argn[$j++])?:~$c=_3145926870[++$i+$j=0];$c!=$d?:print$d);` is also a working alternative

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
Ö€İπ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7///C0R01rjmw43/D///9oQx0THVMdSx0jHTMdCx1zHYNYAA)

Input as a  list of digits.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

```
PI.0@?_SKa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/wFPPwME@Ptg78f///4ZGxiamZuYWlgaGRmYWAA)

#### Explanation

```
       SKa  Sort the command-line argument a by this key function:
    @?_      Index of first occurrence in
PI.0         Pi (3.141592653589793) concatenated with 0
```

If the `0` isn't added, `PI@?0` returns nil, which behaves... [strangely](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/wNPBPj7YO/H///@GRsYmpmbmFpYGhkZmFgA)... when used as a sorting key.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
µ»×₍+=»ḟ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLCtcK7w5figo0rPcK74bifIiwiIiwiMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAiXQ==)

`µ` Sort by

`ḟ` first index in

`»×₍+=»` compressed integer 145926870

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLCtWtp4oKI4bie4bifIiwiIiwiMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAiXQ==) for 6 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 34 bytes

```perl6
*.comb.sort:{3145926870.index: $_}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25sqtVFBLzk9JVbD9r6WXnJ@bpFecX1RiVW1saGJqaWRmYW6gl5mXklphpaASX/vfmqs4sVIBpF5DJV5TLys/M08hLb9IISczL7VYQ/PQbrARGvoxKdr6IB5IwX9DI2MTUzNzC0sDC2NLUwtDcyMLIMMQAA)

```perl6
*\       # WhateverCode lambda (this is the parameter)
.comb    # split into digits
.sort: { # sort by

  3145926870.index: $_ # its index in this number
}
```

Comment: you can save 1 byte by dropping '3' from the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

## k, 19 bytes

```
{x@<"3145926870"?x}
```

Explanation:

```
{                 } /function(x)
    "3145926870"?x  /for each x: "3145926870".index(x)
   <                /get indices with which to sort
 x@                 /sort x by those indices
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Input as a string, output as an array of digit strings

```
¬nUiMP
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=rG5VaU1Q&input=IjAxMjM0NTY3ODk4NzY1NDMyMTAi)

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 100 bytes

```
Input Str1
seq(expr(sub(Str1,I,1)),I,1,length(Str1→A
seq(1+sum(not(cumSum(Ans(I)={3,1,4,5,9,2,6,8,7}))),I,1,dim(Ans→B
SortD(ʟB,ʟA
sum(seq(₁₀^(I-1)ʟA(I),I,1,dim(ʟA
```

Takes input as a string. Outputs a number that is stored in `Ans` and is displayed at the end.